# Google Sheets - conditionally format a cell based on whether the content of the cell appears in a column from a different sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet called `Master` that contains a column of names in cells A1-A60 (e.g. `A1: Ann`,`A2: Bob`,`A3: Chris`, `A4: Donna`, etc.).

I have another sheet called `Subsheet` that contains names that may or may not appear in `Master` (e.g. `A1: Chris`, `A2: Steve`, `A3: Ann`).

I want to highlight the names in `Subsheet` that match names in `Master` - so, in this instance, just `Chris` and `Ann`.

I'm trying conditional formatting using this formula in `Subsheet`:

`=IF(MATCH(A1,INDIRECT("'Master'!$A$1:$A$60"),0))`

But nothing is highlighting. Maybe I'm not using `MATCH` correctly. I think I need to use `INDIRECT` when referring to another sheet in conditional formatting.

What's the best way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem: `IF` is not needed. I removed it and the new formula worked:

`=MATCH(A1,INDIRECT("'Master'!$A$1:$A$60"),0)`